# Joining three tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables named

```
**Student Table**
-------------
id    name
-------------
1     ali
2     ahmed
3     john
4     king

**Course Table**
-------------
id    name
-------------
1     physic
2     maths
3     computer
4     chemistry

**Bridge**
-------------
sid    cid
-------------
1     1
1     2
1     3
1     4
2     1
2     2
3     3
3     4
4     1
4     2
```

Now to show the student name with the course name which he had studied like,

```
**Result**
---------------------------
Student        Course
---------------------------
ahmed         physic
ahmed         maths
ahmed         computer
ahmed         chemistry
ali           physic
ali           maths
john          computer
john          chemistry
king          physic
king          maths
```

I build following query

```
select s.name as Student, c.name as Course from student s, course c join bridge b on c.id = b.cid order by s.name
```

But it does not return the required result...

And what would be for normalized form, if I want to find who is manager over other:

```
**employee**
-------------------
id        name
-------------------
1         ali
2         king
3         mak
4         sam
5         jon

**manage**
--------------
mid      eid
--------------
1         2
1         3
3         4
4         5
```

And wants to get this result:

```
**result**
--------------------
Manager      Staff
--------------------
ali          king
ali          mak
mak          sam
sam          jon
```

Comment: in the first result you wrongly set data for ahmed and ali

Comment: We have 4 tables: name, address, email, phone

SELECT

A.personID,

B.address,

C.emailID,

D.mobnumber

FROM

name AS A

INNER JOIN address AS B ON A.personID = B.personID

INNER JOIN email AS C ON A.personID = C.personID

INNER JOIN phone AS D ON A.personID = D.personID

This is assuming personID is present in all the tables.

This query would display Person ID, Address, Email, Phone number where person ID is same in all the tables since it's an inner join.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Simply use:

```
select s.name "Student", c.name "Course"
from student s, bridge b, course c
where b.sid = s.sid and b.cid = c.cid
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476029/multiple-table-select-vs-join-performance

Comment: Nice and simple, but FWIW consider the following blog re this syntax: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13476050/199364

Comment: NO, NO, NO, NO, NO! Don't use this legacy, ancient, over 25 year old join syntax any more! Use Explicit joins like in [this answer!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709583/575376)

Answer (score 252):

Use ANSI syntax and it will be a lot more clear how you are joining the tables:

```
SELECT s.name as Student, c.name as Course 
FROM student s
    INNER JOIN bridge b ON s.id = b.sid
    INNER JOIN course c ON b.cid  = c.id 
ORDER BY s.name
```

Comment: @Muhammad: Our answers are the same, they differ only in syntax. If you are not aware of `ANSI` syntax, it is well worth your time to learn it. It will help you avoid `JOIN` errors like you have made in the future.

Answer (score 17):

For normalize form

```
select e1.name as 'Manager', e2.name as 'Staff'
from employee e1 
left join manage m on m.mid = e1.id
left join employee e2 on m.eid = e2.id
```

Comment: Does the order matter in `m.mid = e1.id` and `m.eid = e2.id`?

Comment: @Pathros No, order does not matter, in those expressions.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
JOIN user_clockits uc ON u.user_id=uc.user_id
JOIN clockits cl ON cl.clockits_id=uc.clockits_id
WHERE user_id = 158
```

Comment: This answer looks very similar to answers already given 5 years earlier. What about your answer do you feel is important, and missing from existing answers?

Answer (score 2):

Don't join like that. It's a really really bad practice!!! It will slow down the performance in fetching with massive data. For example, if there were 100 rows in each tables, database server have to fetch `100x100x100 = 1000000` times. It had to fetch for `1 million` times. To overcome that problem, join the first two table that can fetch result in minimum possible matching(It's up to your database schema). Use that result in Subquery and then join it with the third table and fetch it. For the very first join --> `100x100= 10000` times and suppose we get 5 matching result. And then we join the third table with the result --> `5x100 = 500.` Total fetch = `10000+500 = 10500` times only. And thus, the performance went up!!!

Answer (score 1):

join query with three tables and we want two values from the same column we set the alias name for every table in the joins. Same table name also declare as a different names.

```
const sql = `select p.ID,p.purchaseamount,urs.name as 
            buyername,pd.productname,
            pd.amount,urs1.name as sellername
            from  purchases p
            left join products pd on p.productid=pd.ID
            left join users urs on p.userid=urs.ID 
            left join users urs1 on  pd.userid=urs1.ID`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
employees.id, 
CONCAT(employees.f_name," ",employees.l_name) AS   'Full Name', genders.gender_name AS 'Sex', 
depts.dept_name AS 'Team Name', 
pay_grades.pay_grade_name AS 'Band', 
designations.designation_name AS 'Role' 
FROM employees 
LEFT JOIN genders ON employees.gender_id = genders.id 
LEFT JOIN depts ON employees.dept_id = depts.id 
LEFT JOIN pay_grades ON employees.pay_grade_id = pay_grades.id 
LEFT JOIN designations ON employees.designation_id = designations.id 
ORDER BY employees.id;
```

You can JOIN multiple TABLES like this example above.

Comment: There already are multiple answers, from years earlier, that show "joining multiple tables". What does your answer add to the discussion?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a point to previous answers that in MySQL we can either use

```
table_factor syntax
```

OR

```
joined_table syntax
```

[mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

**Table_factor example**

```
SELECT prd.name, b.name 
FROM products prd, buyers b
```

**Joined Table example**

```
SELECT prd.name, b.name 
FROM products prd
 left join buyers b on b.bid = prd.bid;
```

FYI: Please ignore the fact the the left join on the joined table example doesnot make much sense (in reality we would use some sort of join table to link buyer to the product table instead of saving buyerID in product table).

Answer (score 0):

```
Query for three table join and limit set

SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.follower_userid, t2.*, t3.login_thumb, t3.login_name, 
  t3.bio, t3.account_status, t3.gender
     FROM videos t2
      LEFT JOIN follower t1
        ON t1.follower_userid = t2.user_id 
         LEFT JOIN videos_user t3 
          ON t1.follower_userid  = t3.login_userid
           WHERE t1.following_userid='$userid'
            LIMIT $startpoint , $limit) AS ID 
             ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
SELECT s.name AS Student, c.name AS Course 
FROM student s 
  LEFT JOIN (bridge b CROSS JOIN course c) 
    ON (s.id = b.sid AND b.cid = c.id);
```

Comment: This answer adds nothing new to this question and uses strange (if not plain wrong syntax, I'd be surprised if this was even valid in MySQL).

Comment: I disagree with AeroX.  Ansi join syntax is meant to disambiguate problems with the old school comma/where join syntax.  I'm looking to see if MySql supports ansi join syntax specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Query to join more than two tables:

```
SELECT ops.field_id, ops.option_id, ops.label
FROM engine4_user_fields_maps AS map 
JOIN engine4_user_fields_meta AS meta ON map.`child_id` = meta.field_id
JOIN engine4_user_fields_options AS ops ON map.child_id = ops.field_id 
WHERE map.option_id =39 AND meta.type LIKE 'outcomeresult' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: There already are multiple answers, from years earlier, that show "joining multiple tables". What does your answer add to the discussion?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve there are lot newer than my answer can you delete them all ? In my answer it is simpler to use with multiple condition like number and string