# MySQL, insert values in all rows except id

Tags: mysql, sql

how is possible to insert values in a table except the id(which I've set as a PK) without specifying all the column names?

Comment: `insert into t values (default, 1, 2, 3 ...)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO ... SELECT without detailing all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297484/insert-into-select-without-detailing-all-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `id` is auto-incremented, MySQL will still auto-increment if you insert `NULL`.  So, you *can* do the following:

```
create table t (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    x int
);

insert into t
    select null, 2;

insert into t
    select null, 3;
```

That said, I recommend (almost) always including all the columns in an `insert`.  So I strongly recommend:

```
insert into t (x)
    select 2;

insert into t (x)
    select 3;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. Just out of curiosity, why do you recommend, "always include all the columns in an `INSERT`"?