# Get columnnames as string sepparated by comma / list

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am doing some inserts with some of my tables and all fields but a few need to be inserted or updated. [Like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297484/insert-into-select-without-detailing-all-columns).
Is there a quick way to get the columns of a table returned as a string so i can copy them into my sql query?
For example i have a table:

```
create table myTable1
(
column1                   integer  not null,
column2                   integer  not null ,
column3                   integer  not null,
column4                   integer  not null,
column5                   integer  not null,
...a lot more fields...
)
```

And later i want to insert something from another table  `myTable2` that has the same fields (dont question my ways and why i have two identical tables).

```
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, ...
FROM table_source
```

But the tables have so many fields it is cumbersome to write them donw manualy and it would be faster to have a string where i can just delete the column names i dont need. Is there a nice query that ouputs `"column1, column2, column3, column4, ..."` so i dont have to write that myself and can copy tha into my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer quickly.

```
SELECT table_catalog, string_agg(column_name, ', ')
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'mySchema'
   AND table_name   = 'myTable' GROUP  BY 1;
```

This query does the trick for me.