# Insert query with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create an SQL query wherein I need to check to sum of columns from 2 tables and then insert a new row into another table if the condition is satisfied. I know I can use a stored procedure with explicit locking but want to know is it is possible to do it in a single SQL query. I wrote the following but it gives syntax error in MySQL workbench

```
INSERT INTO table1 (`col1`, `col2`) 
VALUES ('abc', 'xyz') WHERE 
(
((select 
COUNT(*) from table2 t2 where t2.id = 1)
+ (select sum(t3.counter) from table3 t3 
WHERE t3.id = 1)) < (select t4.total_allowed 
FROM table4 t4 where t4.id = 1)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done because you can [insert the results of a select query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

```
INSERT INTO table1 (`col1`, `col2`) 
SELECT 'abc', 'xyz'
FROM DUAL WHERE 
(
((select 
COUNT(*) from table2 t2 where t2.id = 1)
+ (select sum(t3.counter) from table3 t3 
WHERE t3.id = 1)) < (select t4.total_allowed 
FROM table4 t4 where t4.id = 1)
);
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch.   I'll add the following as reference.   [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253302/insert-into-select-for-all-mysql-columns).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `INSERT` Syntax does not support the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Then is there any other way to check for this condition in an SQL statement in MySQL?

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to use multiple queries.

Comment: But won't multiple queries suffer from race condition? (assuming I am using JDBC to execute the queries in single transaction). Is stored procedure the only way to avoid this?

Comment: Look if REPLACE query gets your job done, in transaction it shouldn't create any problem

Comment: but i think REPLACE is probably not your solution.