# Sub query returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Below is my mysql Query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_user_Details (
    user_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    user_name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    user_email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO temp_user_Details (user_id, user_name, user_email)
    (SELECT user_id, CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) AS UserName, email
        FROM users WHERE reportingManager = "abcd");
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error Code: 1242.
>
> Subquery returns more than 1 row.

I am no able to understand what exaclty is the error as in `users` table `user_id` column is primary key and auto incremental.

Comment: just take out the `(` and `)` you don't need it on an insert statement and mysql can't deal with it.

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253302/insert-into-select-for-all-mysql-columns. You can insert many values and columns at once.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis I am using the same syntax as mentioned in Stack you shared. But m facing problem.

Comment: Really? What problem? I have test it and it works fine.

Comment: Do you have any triggers?

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis No no trigger is defined.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. My guess is that it is caused by the parentheses? Have you tried removing them, like this? Also, the alias has no use being there.

```
INSERT INTO temp_user_Details (user_id,user_name,user_email)
 SELECT user_id,CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name),email
FROM users WHERE reportingManager = 'abcd';
```

Comment: Ya i have tried this also, no luck. I also tried renaming the column names in temporary table. But the result is same.

Comment: @RahulMunjal This is probably a shot in the dark, but are you sure that those two queries are the *only* thing you are running, and the error is not in another query that comes after your two?

Comment: I am sure @Ruslan. only these two queries are present in my stored procedure. Nothing else is present.

Comment: @RahulMunjal `show variables where variable_name in ('innodb_version','version_comment')`  says?

Comment: `innodb_version : 5.6.26`.

`version_comment: google`

Comment: It should work. Try: WHERE reportingManager IN 'abcd' (just in case').