# INSERT INTO SELECT doesnt work properly

Tags: mysql, vba

I'm using VBA on ACCESS.I have a weird problem. Here's is the main query

```
INSERT INTO [Temp2]  ([Prodotto pulizie],Materiale,Compatibility) VALUES 
(SELECT CD.[Prodotto pulizie],CD.Materiale,CD.Risultato 
FROM [Compatibilità_detergenti] as CD 
WHERE CD.[Prodotto pulizie] = 'P1' and CD.Fonte = 'INTERNA' and CD.Materiale = 'ABS;);
```

It tells me that there is a sintax error but if i try the insert and the select separatley they work , in fact

`INSERT INTO [Temp2]  ([Prodotto pulizie],Materiale,Compatibility) VALUES ('P1','INTERNA','ABS')` **works!**

```
SELECT CD.[Prodotto pulizie],CD.Materiale,CD.Risultato 
FROM [Compatibilità_detergenti] as CD 
WHERE CD.[Prodotto pulizie] = 'P1' and CD.Fonte = 'INTERNA' and CD.Materiale = 'ABS;
```

**works!**
The SELECT returns exactley the record i manually inserted in INSERT.
So basically the problem only appears when i merge insert and select, is there any sintax error you can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about the vba but as i checked your query you write VALUES. remove this according to mysql 
try this

```
INSERT INTO [Temp2]  ([Prodotto pulizie],Materiale,Compatibility)  
SELECT CD.[Prodotto pulizie],CD.Materiale,CD.Risultato 
FROM [Compatibilità_detergenti] as CD 
WHERE CD.[Prodotto pulizie] = 'P1' and CD.Fonte = 'INTERNA' and CD.Materiale = 'ABS';
```

[INSERT INTO...SELECT for all MySQL columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253302/insert-into-select-for-all-mysql-columns)

Comment: Pasted your code but tells me syntax error on the WHERE line

Comment: two changes i have done in your query first remove the `VALUES` and second is single quate `'` in the last.

Comment: for more helo accept my answer so i can do help for other. its point appreciate me for help other