# Error nesting select statement into insert statement MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

Hey Everyone,

```
insert into IP values (select * from Proxies where Accs_On_IP = 0);
```

What is wrong with this? The columns from IP and Proxies are the same (just migrating some out of one table into another). Any help or resources would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the syntax `insert into table select` without `values` -- or does mysql allow that?

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5253322/1073631

Comment: First comment worked :) Answer so I can accept it thanks so much