# select statement inside insert statement in sql returns multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following structured query in mysql. But its returning a error. Basically, I want to get value from existing table and instert into new table. I tried the following, but got error;

```
INSERT INTO `table1`(
    `first`,`second`,`third`) VALUES(

    (SELECT table2.timemodified FROM `xtable` AS table2,`ytable` AS table3 
        WHERE table3.id = table2.contextid),

    (SELECT table4.id FROM `ztable` AS table4,`ytable` AS table3 WHERE table4.id = table3.instanceid),

    (SELECT murs.id FROM `table5` AS murs,
    `xtable` AS table2, 
    `wtable` AS table6, 
    `ytable` AS table3, 
    `vtable` AS table7 
    WHERE murs.id = table2.userid AND table6.id = table2.roleid AND table3.id = table2.contextid AND table7.instance = table3.instanceid AND table6.id =3)
);
```

I tested but the error is : `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`. The problem is I am getting more than single record from the `select` query inside `insert`. How can I remove such error.

Comment: Do you want to insert multiple rows ro just one row.

Comment: Yes, I want to insert multiple rows

Comment: then use : insert into table (value1, value2, value3) select x,y,z from table2

Comment: I didn't get you, will you elaborate your answer please :)

Comment: Your subqueries (`select` queries) is returning more than one row I guess. I would suggest to try adding `limit 1` in each `select` query and then try once if it goes alright then the query is correct you need to find a way to limit the rows returned.

Comment: Yes, select  is returning more than one row, but I want to insert them all.

Comment: Then can you use stored procedure for this? (the only solution I know to loop upon the data)

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253302/insert-into-select-for-all-mysql-columns

Comment: @lordkain It is not duplicate. The referred question deals with only one subquery

Comment: same problem, same answer, sounds duplicate with me. but back to vijayrana, is this helpfull for you?

Comment: i don't think this is dublicate to refered link anyway thanks for answering. but still stucked

Answer (score 3):

the total query looks something like below. where you have so replace the * with column names you want to select!

```
INSERT INTO table1(first,second,third)

-- replace * with columns name first,second,third
select * from (
-- START YOU'RE select query
(SELECT table2.timemodified FROM `xtable` AS table2,`ytable` AS table3 
        WHERE table3.id = table2.contextid),

    (SELECT table4.id FROM `ztable` AS table4,`ytable` AS table3 WHERE table4.id = table3.instanceid),

    (SELECT murs.id FROM `table5` AS murs,
    `xtable` AS table2, 
    `wtable` AS table6, 
    `ytable` AS table3, 
    `vtable` AS table7 
    WHERE murs.id = table2.userid AND table6.id = table2.roleid AND table3.id = table2.contextid AND table7.instance = table3.instanceid AND table6.id =3)
-- END YOU'RE select query
)
```

I moved you're select statements into a subquery so you can use the total result of the subquerys to you're advantage.

Comment: Would you please explain :)