# How do i insert a row with select statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble inserting with select in PHP.

- the statement runs fine in MYSQL
- The main problem is on the Select statement in PHP.
- I check on database `rolename` is inserted with the value object
- The statement adds new row into "login" with value `$login` and "rolename" with value from another table which store default rolename hence the select statement.

```
$db->insert(Common::prefixTable("roles_user"), array("login" =>
$userLogin, "rolename" => $db->query('SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(option_value),":",1)),2)),4)) FROM '. Common::prefixTable("option").' WHERE option_name = "RolesManager"')));
```

Please help me check how can I use select statement with insert statement in `php`.

Thanks

Comment: Why even assign it to a variable. How about just an `Insert tblA (col1, ...) select colA, ... from [the rest including join or whatever]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use select and insert this way:-

```
$db->insert("test_user", array("login" => $userLogin, "rolename" => $db->query('SELECT role_name FROM "test" WHERE role_name = "manager"')));
```

Your select query provide a object, from this object take value of `role_name`.

```
$roleData = $db->query('SELECT role_name FROM "test" WHERE role_name = "manager"')
```

For example if you assign role name to a variable called `$role`. Use this $role to insert.

```
$role = $roleData[0]['role_name'];

$db->insert("test_user", array("login" => $userLogin, "rolename" =>$role));
```

And why you are selecting `role_name` from query as you already know role name `"manager"`, Use direct query as like:-

```
$db->insert("test_user", array("login" => $userLogin, "rolename" =>"manager"));
```

Comment: Hi, Rakesh, your logic solve my problem, however, the code wouldn't run, this part `$roleData = $db->query('SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(option_value),":",1)),2)),4)) AS Val FROM '. Common::prefixTable("option").' WHERE option_name = "RolesManager"');        
        $role = $roleData[0]['Val'];`

Comment: Solved using `$db->fetchAll()` instead of `$db->query()`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> How do I insert a row with a select statement

You cannot. `INSERT` is to add a row. `SELECT` is to return rows. These are two mutually exclusive operations.

Your question is analogous to: How do I write a new line by reading from a page?

Edit:  Based on your comments below I think I understand: You are trying to `insert` a record with information from a `select` operation. The solution is to put it all in one query, and use the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax. You would do something such as:

```
INSERT INTO roles_user (login, rolename)
SELECT '$userLogin' as login, option_name as rolename
FROM option
WHERE ...; /*the condition to meet in option table to select option_name*/
LIMIT 1
```

You may need to adjust this to fit your application. Take a look at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253302/insert-into-select-for-all-mysql-columns)

Comment: Beetle it is an orm. You can insert a row using a select stmt you know that.

Comment: But i'm able to run the statement in MySQL, i'm sorry my knowledge with php is very limited, is it that you mean, I can't use select with insert statement in PHP?

Comment: @Drew don't know what `orm` is. Does it have to do with trolling?  @nicker yes that's what I mean. Are you trying to add new data to your table (`insert`) or retrieve data from your table (`select`) ?

Comment: Does what have to do with trolling?

Comment: @Drew talking about `orm`

Comment: @Beetlejuice, i'm inserting a new row, where I need to get value from another table, hence the select statement.

Comment: @nicker Oh I see.  You have an answer from Rakesh Kumar

Comment: @Beetlejuice, Thanks

Comment: @nicker I've added a bit to my answer. Good luck.