# Copy a longblob element from one table to another php-mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Facing a problem in code, how can I extract a `longblob` element from a table, and insert another table that is also a `longblob` with `php`.

To be more specific, I have a table in which a field is of type `longblob`, which contains an image, what I want is to extract this `longblob` image and insert it into another table that also contains a `longblob` field.

Thanks with your suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO...SELECT for all MySQL columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253302/insert-into-select-for-all-mysql-columns)

Comment: that's for all columns (fields)...but you only need one column, your one longblob field...still, it's the same syntax, just specify your one field.