# Multiple Table Select vs. JOIN (performance)

Tags: mysql

When selecting from multiple tables in MySQL, both of the following queries return the same result set.

Is one of these queries *better* or more efficient than the other? From my testing on a small dataset (~2k rows in each table) they both return the same result set in around the same execution time.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products,
    product_meta,
    sales_rights
WHERE 
    (
        products.id = product_meta.product_id
        AND products.id = sales_rights.product_id
    )
    AND (...)
LIMIT 0,10;
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN product_meta ON products.id = product_meta.product_id
JOIN sales_rights ON product_meta.product_id = sales_rights.product_id 
WHERE
    (...)
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Always use the second, its the modern way of doing it!

Comment: Decent DBMS should have a query optimizer that can digest the input query and figure out the best way to run it. So a query optimizer should handle the queries you mentioned equally.

Comment: In my setup Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.06, the "select from t1, t2, t3 where" is 0,016s faster than the equivalent one with "select from t1 inner join t2 on...": 0,094s vs 0,109s. Although there is a loss in readability as the answers point out.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

They are the same, but with a different syntax. So you shouldn't expect any performance difference between the two syntaxes. However the the last syntax(ANS SQL-92 syntax) is the recommended, see these for more details:

- [**Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs.**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
- [**SQL JOIN: is there a difference between USING, ON or WHERE?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654278/sql-join-is-there-a-difference-between-using-on-or-where/5654338#5654338)