# My Sql Query to find data in another field for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I wan to find the data in single mysql query for following sceneraio

Suppose I have a `users` table:

```
id | name
 1 |   A
 2 |   B
```

`events` table:

```
id | event_name  
 1 |     E1
 2 |     E2
```

`event_request_sent` table:

```
id | event_id | user_id
 1 |     1    |    1
 2 |     1    |    2
 3 |     2    |    1
```

I need the output something like that for json output

```
[{
    "event_name": "E1",
    "user_Details": [{
        "name": "A",
        "id": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "B",
        "id": 2
    }]
}, {
    "event_name": "E2",
    "user_Details": [{
        "name": "A",
        "id": "1"
    }]
}]
```

Please help me, I tried using joins but getting 2 entries for event E1 and one for E2 as based in no of users in event_request_sent table. I am not getting the output like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I've edited

Answer (score 0):

```
Select event.events_name, GROUP_CONCAT(user.name) AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(user.id) AS id
from user user_table,
event events_table,
eventreq events_request_table
where
event.id = eventreq.event_id
and user.id = eventreq.user_id
```

I assume this select query would run perfectly.

Comment: Specifying multiple tables in `FROM` clause is an [old-style JOINing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13476050/3745677).

Comment: @lolbas i'm a fresher in programming so i am still learning, but i guess this would work for this question, wouldn't it? I am sorry for my query as it might be unreadable by some experienced people.

Comment: Farhan , Thanks for the answer, but I think you didn't get what I ask for. This is not what I need

Comment: @ak001 I've now used group concat, what it should to is that print the id and name in the same row against the event name, can you check it now if it this is what you want?

Comment: This is not the solution , for more understanding you may refer my question again. & Thanks again for your efforts