# Join multiple columns from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

Looking at this solution:  [MySql Join three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/mysql-join-three-tables)

I see that I can join 3 tables by doing something like this:

```
select s.name "Student", c.name "Course"
from student s, bridge b, course c
where b.sid = s.sid and b.cid = c.cid
```

But it seems like I can only select a single column from each table?  I need to join multiple colums from 3 tables with sys_visits being the main table where userID=contrID (sys_users, sys_visits) and clientID=clientID (sys_client, sys_visits)

```
SELECT pid, clientID, contrID, serviceDate, serviceStart, serviceStop FROM sys_visits
SELECT userGroupID, userID, fname, lname FROM sys_users
SELECT clientID, clientFName, clientLName FROM sys_client ORDER BY clientLName ASC
```

I've tried numerous variations and can't seem to get the syntax correct?

Comment: When you want to join you should use `joins` :) and Ofcourse you can select any number if columns.

Comment: doesn't mysql default to inner join when no join type is specified? But yes in general you can select any/all columns from any number of tables being queried. [edit] and you can base your join on the equivalence of any number of columns as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `ANSI SQL-92` format of join instead.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM    sys_users a
        INNER JOIN sys_visits b
            ON a.userID = b.contrlD
        INNER JOIN sys_client c
            ON b.clientID = c.clientID
```

the use of asterisks in the query indicates that you are selecting *all columns* from the tables. If you want to only choose specific columns, declare the column names explicitly on the query, example:

```
SELECT  a.userGroupID, a.userID, a.fname, a.lname,
        b.*, 
        c.*
FROM    sys_users a
        INNER JOIN sys_visits b
            ON a.userID = b.contrlD
        INNER JOIN sys_client c
            ON b.clientID = c.clientID
```

Comment: I used this one,but in my condition,I have 2 columns with only 1 row filled and one column in the 3rd table with 2 rows filled.So when I fetch,all of this,iam getting only 1 row from all tables!!

Answer (score 1):

You can select any number columns from the tables.

```
    SELECT sv.pid, sv.clientID, sv.contrID, sv.serviceDate, sv.serviceStart, sv.serviceStop, su.userGroupID, su.userID, su.fname, su.lname, sc.clientFName, sc.clientLName 
    FROM sys_visits sv, sys_users su, sys_client sc 
    ORDER BY sc.clientLName ASC
```

Heres another method using `JOINS` **[Recommended]**

```
SELECT sv.pid, sv.clientID, sv.contrID, sv.serviceDate, sv.serviceStart, sv.serviceStop, su.userGroupID, su.userID, su.fname, su.lname, sc.clientFName, sc.clientLName FROM sys_visits sv
JOIN sys_users su ON su.userID = sv.contrID 
JOIN sys_client sc ON sc.clientID = sv.clientID 
ORDER BY sc.clientLName ASC
```

Comment: the second query is fine but the first one produces `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm trying to explain OP multiple table column can be selected on the first query.

Answer (score 1):

Think if you have three tables for example

designation,qualification,specialization and teacher table.Here if you want to join three tables inside teacher table that has teacher_id, teacher_name, designation_id, qualification_id , specialization_id ,status etc...

```
    SELECT 
    t.name as teacher_name,
    d.name as designation_name,
    q.name as qualification_name,
    s.name as specialization_name
       FROM teachers t
    INNER JOIN designation d ON t.designation_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN qualification q ON t.qualification_id = q.id
    INNER JOIN specialization s ON t.specialization_id = s.id
    WHERE t.status = 1;
```