# Newbie trying to solve a MySQL query logic issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm going to try to explain this as simply as possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not very good with designing queries.

I have 3 tables: (I have cut down the unnecessary columns in the users table for this question)

```
USERS:
id,    username,    password

PENDINGREVIEW:
id,    articleid,    requestid,    content,    writerid,    datewritten

ARTICLES:
id,    title,    length,    requestedby,    content,    writtenby,    daterequested,    datecompleted
```

So say I have `review.php`. On `review.php` I want it to show all the articles that are in the `pendingreview` table for a specific user. So something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pendingreview WHERE requestid = $userid (where $userid = the id of the user)
```

What I actually want to display on `review.php` though is a list of articles from the `articles` table and how many articles are in the `pendingreview` table that correspond to each of those articles. The list must only be made up of articles that the user has requested.

So I want `review.php` to look like this:

- `Your "How to build a bike" article request has 3 articles pending review.`
- `Your "How to mow the lawn" article request has 12 articles pending review.`

Any help on how I would do this would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't any question marks. Please try something first. And read [faq]

Comment: What query would I use? I have no idea where to begin!

Comment: @KriiV Your example with `SELECT ...` is heading in a good direction. You'll want to `JOIN` your tables: [mysql-manual] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) and use `count` on the id of your articles...

Comment: You don't need anyone to give you a query. You need to either learn MySql or get someone to work on your project. After this query you'll need another and another...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.title, COUNT(*) TotalPending
FROM    Articles a
        INNER JOIN PendingReview b  
            ON a.ID = b.articleID
WHERE   b.RequestID = 'ID HERE'
GROUP   BY a.title
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.ID = b.articleID WHERE b.RequestID = '3' GROUP BY a.title LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: Thank you so much JW. Itachi, I have tried, I find it all very confusing as to where I should start.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to build your requests:

[MySql Join three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/mysql-join-three-tables)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Joining_Tables_in_MySQL