# How to get data in single query from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have three different tables.

**First Table**

First table is language(id, language_name) // id is primary key.

**Second Table**

Second Table is verse(id,topic_id, verse_text) // id is primary key, topic_id is foreign key.

**Third Table**

Third table is verse_translations(id, verse_id, language_id, translations_text) // id is primary key, language_id is foreign key references with language table, // verse_id is foreign key references with verse table.

**Now My Question is.**

How I can get the list of verse with verse translations and available languages of specific topic_id in one MYSql Query.

As a example i have given below.

```
verse_id | topic_id |    verse    |    verse_translation     |  language |

  1           1        verse here      translation here      English
                                       translation here      Spanish
                                       translation here      Japanese
                                       translation here      Italian
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Look what I found: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: "The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: which type of research do you need ? I have asked a simple question. that i want to get the result as i have described in table shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT verse.id,
  verse.topic_id,
  verse.verse_text,
  verse_translations.translations_text,
  language.language_name
FROM verse
  INNER JOIN verse_translations ON verse.id = verse_translations.verse_id
  INNER JOIN language ON verse_translations.language_id = language.id
WHERE verse.topic_id = 1
```

Keep in mind that all rows are filled. So the the column `topic_id` is `1` all the way.

Comment: Thanks sir 4 your help, but the above query i can write. I need data as i have describe in table shape.

Comment: You need the empty cells you mean? Not gonna happen. PHP can help you with this but MySQL can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to this post [MySql Join three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/mysql-join-three-tables)

Make changes according to your need.