# How to order by using column values in reference table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have query like this,

```
Select f.* from fuel_log f 
where f.transaction_date='2006-05-28 00:00:00' 
order by f.driver.full_name;
```

My problem is, i am not able to order by using `f.driver.full_name`. It says no such column. However, that's correct because, `driver` is reference column in `fuel_log` table. Here i am trying to sort based on values in driver table which is causing a problem. May i know how can in sort based on values in reference table column?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you said driver is referenced column which is common between two tables then you can join both tables to sort it by reference column.

Please modify order by clause as per you need full_name or driver column.

```
Select   f.* 
from     fuel_log f inner join driver d
on       f.driver = d.driver
where    f.transaction_date='2006-05-28 00:00:00' 
order by d.driver;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway, i am already joining table that is fuel_log and fuel_inspection. It is only for simplicity and for better understanding i posted normal query.

Comment: will it allow to join third table also?

Comment: If you're able to join then there shouldn't be any problem while sorting.

Comment: @Kishan_KP yes for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/mysql-join-three-tables

Comment: I am not joining fuel_log and driver table. I am joining fuel_log and fuel_inspection. however, driver is reference column in both of this table.