# Multiple joins on different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
 1. player_list
 2. tournaments
 3. rank_list
```

with the following fields

**player_list**

```
- id, player_id, tournament
```

**tournaments**

```
- id, tournament, rl_month
```

**rank_list**

```
- id, player_id, rl_month, rl_position
```

I want to build a query to find the `rl_position` for a specific `rl_month` of each `player_id` from `rank_list` table on `player_list` table for a specific tournament `(player_list.tournament = tournaments.id)`.

There is also a `FK (rl_month)` between `tournaments` and `rank_list`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a normal join. Check out [this site](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) for joins. also refer to [this question for multiple joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/mysql-join-three-tables)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query which made the trick alhough is a little bit slow because of the FK which are not unique is:

```
select r.id, r.rl_year, t.code, t.tournament, t.rl_month, 
r.rl_pos, r.rl_pts, p.player_id, p.name, p.gender, p.assoc, p.cat
from fab_plist p 
inner join fab_rl r 
on p.player_id = r.player_id
inner join fab_tournaments t 
on p.tournament = t.id where r.rl_pos is not null 
AND p.tournament = t.id AND r.rl_month = 
(select fab_tournaments.rl_month from fab_tournaments where fab_tournaments.id = t.id)
order by r.rl_pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select rl_position  from rank_list r 
inner join player_list p 
on p.player_id = r.player_id
inner join tournaments t p.tournament =t.id and t.rl_month='Assign month'
```

Comment: Tried this but it returns records that doesn't belong to specific tournament.id on the player_list.