# How to Join multiple tables?

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried this query for two tables and it worked, but if I want to do it for many tables how it is done?

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *  FROM assignments 
                   inner join Customers on assignments.Customer_ID = customers.Customer_ID";
//assignments and customers are tables
```

Comment: Provide DDL with some sample data and expected result out of the sample data.

Comment: just keep saying `inner join X on y.a = x.a`

Comment: Are you asking for help w.r.t SQL Query ? If yes, check my answer.  

If not, kindly clarify on DDL & sample data & expected output.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3709583/2558060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider agents,customer,orders to be your tables & you gotta join them.

```
SELECT 
    a.ord_num,
    b.cust_name,
    a.cust_code,  
    c.agent_code,
    b.cust_city  
FROM agents c, customer b, orders a  
WHERE b.cust_city = c.working_area  
    AND a.cust_code = b.cust_code  
    AND a.agent_code = c.agent_code;
```

Regards!

Comment: what is a , b, c ? is the name of tables ?

Comment: Line 3: a is orders, b is customer, c is agents.  
This is called Alias-ing.

Comment: You can also do Alias-ing using keyword "as": 

"FROM agents as c,customer as b,orders as a "

Comment: Accept the answer if you understood it. So that it'll be helpful to others.

Regards.

Comment: I gotta love that you aliased orders to a, agents to c and customers to b :) Mnemonic disaster. {edit} I tend to alias tables all the time (for space and readability) and I alias them by the initials of individual words (to remember who's who).

Comment: Memory tuner :P Thanks for that :D

Answer (score 1):

Here I am giving one example. You can create queries like this one:

```
select 
    * 
from tblA a 
     inner join tblB b 
         on a.id = b.id 
     inner join tblC 
         on a.id = c.id 
     inner join tblD 
         on a.id = d.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL management studio, right click and select "Design Query in Editor". This is the easiest way to join your tables (it's visual)

Comment: Good solution when someone is trying to do querying from the workbench !

Comment: SQL Management Studio is graphical tool for work with MSSQL Server, not with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
SELECT * FROM assignments AS a, customers AS c WHERE a.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID;
```