# How do I find the directors for the movies directly?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have three separate tables labeled directors, studios, and movie.

Directors columns: `id, name, dob, nationality, gender`.

Studios columns: `id, name, founding date, and director_id` 
(Foreign Key is `director_id`)

Movies: `ID, name, length, studio_id` (foreign key is `studios_id`)

I have to find all the directors who directed movies with the name awakening but I have no idea how to use foreign keys properly. Best I've come up with was

`SELECT name, studio_id FROM studios WHERE name = "awakening"`

I have no idea what I'm doing. Please help.

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: I'm not sure why your schema links "studio" and "director" (probably just what your professor set up when he made the homework assignment) but what you're looking for is a [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/mysql-join-three-tables

Comment: Haha, close. I'm reviewing for a test and realized I had forgotten databases stuff over the break.

Comment: Thanks for the link paul.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use INNER JOIN on your query

```
SELECT d.id, d.name FROM director d INNER JOIN studios s ON d.id = s.director_id INNER JOIN movie m ON s.id = m.studio_id WHERE m.name = "awakening";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Movies.name as movie_name, Directors.name as director_name 
FROM Movies
JOIN Studios ON (Movies.studio_id = Studios.id)
JOIN Directors ON (Studios.director_id = Directors.id)
WHERE Movies.name = 'awakening';
```