# Select Join Table A and Table B while displaying Table B items based on Table A's foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the midst of writing an SQL statement and I have a problem joining both tables (let's call it Table Enrollment & Product) based on a foreign key column from table Enrollment's column StudentID. The StudentID is read from a variable $StudentID.

Enrollment table

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------+

| EnrollmentID | StudentID | ProductID |

+--------------+-----------+-----------+

| 1            | 5         | 1         |

| 2            | 5         | 2         |

|3             | 7         | 2         |

|4             | 7         | 3         |

|5             | 9         | 5         |

+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Product Table

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+

| ProductID | ProductName | ProductDate|

+-----------+-------------+------------+

|1          | ProductA    | 1/1/2017   |

|2          | ProductB    | 1/2/2017   |

|3          | ProductC    | 1/3/2017   |

|4          | ProductD    | 1/4/2017   |

+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

This is the SQL statement so far i've come up and having trouble with:

```
"SELECT product.ProductName, product.ProductDate
                                FROM enrollment WHERE StudentID = '$StudentID'
                                RIGHT JOIN product ON enrollment.productid = product.productid";
```

If $StudentID is 5. I want it to display all items from ProductID that is associated with StudentID 5. Which in this case, Product A and Product B will be the output.

Comment: It sounds as though `Enrollment` is a [**bridging table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), and that `StudentID` is coming from a **third** table (`Student`?). You'll also need to join that table as well :)

Comment: Yes it's from a third table. But no columns are used from that table but only the `StudentID`. I'm not familiar with joining three tables.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're not **displaying** the data from the third table, you're still **using** the ID to 'associate' the two tables together. To join the three tables together, you essentially just need to tack another `JOIN` at the end (between `Enrollment` and `Student`). Here's [**some examples**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/mysql-join-three-tables) to help with that :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. This is what i wrote `SELECT product.ProductName, product.ProductDate
                                FROM enrollment WHERE StudentID = '$StudentID'
                                JOIN student ON enrollment.studentid = student.studentid
                                RIGHT JOIN product ON enrollment.productid = product.productid"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your sql code, I assume you use PHP to generate sql query. Please use `{$variable}` when ever you want to include variable value inside string in PHP. And you have to join the table first and then apply condition. Use the below query,

```
"SELECT product.ProductName, product.ProductDate FROM enrollment inner join student ON enrollment.studentid = student.studentid  RIGHT JOIN product ON enrollment.productid = product.productid WHERE enrollment.StudentID = '{$StudentID}' "
```

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @StudentID INT = 5;

SELECT p.productname, 
       p.productdate 
FROM   Enrollment e 
       RIGHT JOIN producttable p 
               ON e.productid = p.productid 
WHERE  e.studentid = @StudentID