# MySql Join more than 2 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 tables and want to get into the "inventory" table where user_id = user_id and want to show all "ownedskins" from a user with this id.

How can I do this?

Thanks for all replys!

[The three tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Iny.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining three tables using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/joining-three-tables-using-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you know the `user_id`, you could do that with a single `join`, like this:

```
SELECT
  ownedskins.*
FROM
  ownedskins JOIN inventory ON ownedskins.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
WHERE
  inventory.user_id = x
```

Where `x` is the id of the user you want

You can also do it with alias to make it look cleaner:

```
SELECT
  os.*
FROM
  ownedskins os JOIN inventory i ON os.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
WHERE
  i.user_id = x
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Do you also know how to get the id from the Player that has logged in before? So I can use this ID for the x. I use the following Code to login in another script:                                                                 [link](https://imgur.com/a/lELVD)

Comment: No problem. About your other question, what do you mean by `logged in before`? If you're trying to get the `id` of the user that's logging in, you should change your query to `SELECT user_id,userpassword FROM ...` and then store `$row['user_id']`

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/fi1LE) I want to call the $_SESSION['user_logged'] in another script, how is that possible? Cause this stores the ID from the user that logged in in my Script.

Comment: Like I said earlier, you should change your password query from `SELECT userpassword FROM...` to `SELECT user_id,userpassword FROM...`, so you can get both `user_id` and `userpassword`. Then, when the login is successful you're able to do this: `$_SESSION['user_logged'] = $row['user_id'];` without more queries since your first one already brings that field

Comment: Now I have the second script and want to call the ID but it doesnt work... I get the "Something went wrong". Can you help? [link](https://pastebin.com/994b5AYH)

Comment: How are you setting the variable?

Comment: It looks good. Have you modified the way PHP handles sessions? What's the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);`?

Comment: So, you're calling the PHP from Unity?

Comment: Then the problem might be `WWW` doesn't manage sessions by default, so you should try something like this: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/255077/view.html

Answer (score 1):

Joining more than 2 tables with MySql example:

```
SELECT    i.*
FROM      ownedskins o
          JOIN inventory i
              ON o.inventory_id=i.inventory_id
          JOIN user u
              ON u.user_id = i.user_id
WHERE     u.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using joins is very easy, use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id2 = t3.id
```

You can also use JOIN variants like LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following tables:

```
Driver
Car
Keys
```

If you want access to all 3 of them you could do the following:

```
SELECT D.name, C.plate, K.state
FROM Driver D, Car C, Keys K
WHERE C.key_id = K.id and
      K.owner_id = D.id;
```

---

Using JOINS:

```
SELECT    D.name, C.plate, K.state
FROM      Car C JOIN Keys K
              ON C.key_id = K.id JOIN Driver D
                  ON K.owner_id = D.id;
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.