# How to connecting 3 tables which are connected to each other

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my MySQL joining 3 tables. Can 3 table will connect to each other? what do I write?

[union of 3 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC4Rl.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your question. However, joins between more than two tables aren't actually uncommon. Warning though, SQL (you should add that tag and one for the actual DB) knows both `JOIN` and `UNION`, don't mix those up.

Comment: Check previous answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/joining-three-tables-using-mysql

Comment: please check my union tables below my question.