# How to join country state and city in a single query?

Tags: php, join, mysqli

1 Table Name: Country

```
id  country_name
1   India
2   America
```

2 Table Name: States

```
id  state_name country_id
1   punjab      1
2   california  2
```

3 Table Name: Cities

```
id  city_name  state_id
1   Ludhiana   1
2   Chico      2
```

here is my code which i had written...
Visit: tinyurl.com/myphpmysqli

At this time i'm getting a result if there are thousands of records in each table then how do i fetch using a single query with mysqli joins??

Country -> states -> cities

like this..
[Here my image the data will look like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i96Sz.png)

PHP version: 5.6.16
phpmyadmin: Version information: 4.5.2

Comment: post code here as text, don't ask us to follow some unknown tinyurl link to see your code

Comment: Have a look at this question, it will give you a good idea as they had a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/joining-three-tables-using-mysql

Answer (score 2):

try this. hope it will work for you

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM country c
        JOIN States s on c.id= s.country_id
        JOIN Cities ci on s.id = ci.state_id"
```