# SQL : Join of inner join

Tags: sql, join

I am a beginner on SQL.
I have 3 tables (A,B and C) and I want to extract only the part of A that is part of B or C.

Here is an image of what I want to extract (in red) :
[image]

I know that the intersection between A and C is obtain by :

```
A inner join C on #the keys
```

and between A and B :

```
A inner join B on #the keys
```

My question is : how to join/add those two inner join ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining three tables using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/joining-three-tables-using-mysql)

Comment: `... from a join b on ... join c on ...`?

Comment: A join B on ... join C on ... will not take the intersection between A and C only

Comment: @LCMa . . . Sample data and desired results is much more meaningful than something theoretical.  There are many ways to do this, depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: That picture communicates nothing. What does it have to do with joins? [Re joins & Venn diagrams.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642928/3404097) The rest is also unclear. Please give a [mcve] for your actual problem.

Comment: @philipxy the picture clearly communicates that the OP wants only the data from A that has crossover with B and C.

Comment: @NicholasGentile "crossover with" doesn't mean anything. Tables are bags but Venn & Euler diagrams work for sets & not bags, so it's not clear exactly what the image legend is. The diagram circle labels & "intersection between" suggest the circles enclose rows of tables, but in "A inner join C on #the keys" (which isn't clear) the "the keys" not being "all columns" suggests that it's not intersection but some other join & that the circles enclose not row values but key subrow values. The question is not clear. You are jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @NicholasGentile I already left a comment 2 years ago when the question was posted saying neither the image nor the post were clear, and I gave links explaining why. No response. Anyway the odds that the asker ever thought that sticking "#the keys" in an ON was clear are zero. I have not trashed anything, you are shooting the messenger. PS The asker self-answered, and that answer is also not clear about what it's proposing or how that answers whatever it takes the question to be.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `exists`:

```
select . . . 
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.? = a.?) or
      exists (select 1 from c where b.? = a.?);
```

If you want columns from all tables, then use `left join` and use a `where` clause:

```
select . . .
from a left join
     b
     on . . . left join
     c
     on . . .
where c.? is not null or b.? is not null;
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally found how to do that ... And it is very easy and fast :

```
SELECT ... FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON ....

UNION

SELECT ... FROM A 
INNER JOIN C ON ....
```

Answer (score -2):

You got it. BTW, your picture is not correct, I think. If you are looking for records which are part of A and part of B "OR" C, the circles B and C should be without intersection. You draw records which are part of A and part of B "AND" C instead. If you draw it correctly, you'll see your final union result clearly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also there's no reason to say the picture is not correct; assuming the tables are sets not bags, it's a reasonable interpretation of the English. Although the question isn't clear. Your "should be without intersection" is wrong for a Venn diagram.