# merging 2 Databases MySQL

Tags: mysql, merge

i am relatively new to database-management and hope you could help me out:

I have 2 different databases with labels.
The 1st one has a table with many informations(like 14 colums, 9 of them with foreign Key).

One of those colums is idIPaddress(guides you to another ip table with ip´s)

The 2nd database only has a table with 3 colums (id, label, ip)

now here is the problem: I want to merge them by comparing the 2nd db´s label with a column of the 1st db(the one with many colums) and set the right id into idIPadress(for foreign-linking).

I thought of a vlookup in excel, DBforge(not quite the right actions) and some other options.

But before handling it via vlookup i thought i could ask here so maybe anyone has dealt with such a problem already and maybe has an elegant solution for me.

Thanks for helping

Martin

Comment: JOIN (a suitable version) of.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/joining-three-tables-using-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join between tables in two different databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698378/join-between-tables-in-two-different-databases)

Comment: not really. I don´t just want to just join, i want to merge(insert) 1 db into another with a comparison-parameter (label in this case) and add the ip-column and id into a different table of db1.